# Codeigniter, facebook SDK 5, not working

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I have followed this tutorial https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v4-to-v5 and so far I have managed to integrate the SDK into codeignitor etc

In my controller I have

```
function facebook(){
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id'     => 'xxx',
      'app_secret' => 'xxx',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['email', 'user_posts']; // optional
    $callback = 'http://localhost/project/api/index.php/social/facebook-callback';
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);
    echo $loginUrl;
}
```

And this generates a url for me. I then follow this link and it takes me to facebook I click ok then it goes to a redirect page. 
On that page i have

```
function facebook_callback(){
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id'     => 'xxx',
      'app_secret' => 'xxx',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);


$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // There was an error communicating with Graph
  echo $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
  // User authenticated your app!
  // Save the access token to a session and redirect
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
  // Log them into your web framework here . . .
  // Redirect here . . .
  exit;
} elseif ($helper->getError()) {
  // The user denied the request
  // You could log this data . . .
  var_dump($helper->getError());
  var_dump($helper->getErrorCode());
  var_dump($helper->getErrorReason());
  var_dump($helper->getErrorDescription());
  // You could display a message to the user
  // being all like, "What? You don't like me?"
  exit;
}

    // If they've gotten this far, they shouldn't be here
    http_response_code(400);
    exit;
}
```

When I land on the page I get as an error

**Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing.**

Why does this happen? Is this to do with the sessions? I have followed the tutorial and nothing seems to work. Any other documents I have found I have tried to for example     ***session_start();*** and ***Overwriting Persistent Data*** but to no avail!

Any point in the right direction will be very much appreciated. I have googled this loads and there are no clear answers.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok answer found!

Pay special attention to the **Overwriting Persistent Data** in the tutorial! So it is a session related issue. Also doing it late at night is ill-advised.

What I missed was that you have to start the process from scratch, ie facebook route and get a brand new url link, then paste that link in the url, and you will be redirected to the facebook_callback. And you will then get the data you require.

Answer here incase someone else falls in the "what the hell is going on (when late at night trap)!"